# Не выводит данные из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Я написал форму входа на сайт. Добавил 1 пользователя и если ввожу данные от него, то все работает, но стоит ввести данные от другого, так сайт не пропускает и крашится.

Листинг PHP скрипта

```
<?php
    require_once "func/connect.php";
    global $mysqli;
    session_start();

    $user = array();
    $login = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    connectDB();

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM `user` where `login` = '".$login."' AND `pass` = '".$pass."'");
    var_dump($result);
    if($result)
    {   $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    var_dump($user);
        if (count($user) != 0) {
            if ($user['admin'] == "yes") {
                setcookie("name", $user['name'], time()+7200, "/");
                setcookie("surname", $user['surname'], time()+7200, "/");
                setcookie("admin", $user['admin'], time()+7200, "/");
            } else {
                setcookie("name", $user['name'], time()+7200, "/");
                setcookie("surname", $user['surname'], time()+7200, "/");
            }
            header('Location: ../Pages/index.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Неверный логин или пароль";
            header('Location: ../../login.php');
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Ошибка запроса на сервер. Попробуйте позже.";
        header('Location: ../../login.php');
    }

    closeDB();
```

[image: Непосредственно сама ошибка]

Comment: Это конечно всё очень плохо. и твоя проблема с ненужным count() это просто ерунда по сравнению с остальными. Я понимаю что проблема в качестве учебников, а точнее видеокурсов, но купи хотя бы Котерова. У тебя тут не авторизация, а дыра. Любой пятиклассник зайдет под твоим акком вообще не зная пароля.

Comment: Этот сайт работает как показательный, тут не стоит смотреть со стороны безопасности, тут просто необходимо, чтобы он создавал куки

Answer (score 1):

Да, соглашусь с предыдущим комментатором, все плохо. Используйте PDO для работы с mysql.

ПРИМЕР:

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'имябазы');
define('DB_USER', 'юзер');
define('DB_PASS', 'пароль');
define('DB_CHAR', 'utf8');

class DB
{
    protected static $instance = null;

    public function __construct() {}
    public function __clone() {}

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            $opt  = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => TRUE,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
            );
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
            
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }

    public static function run($sql, $args = null)
    {
        $stmt = self::instance()->prepare($sql);
        
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}


$login = $_POST["login"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$query = "SELECT  from user WHERE login = ? AND pass = ?";
$res = DB::run($query, array($login, md5($pass)))->fetch();
```

1. В res будет ассоциативный массив строки из БД, делайте с ней, что хотите.
2. Самое элементарное - храним в базе не открытые пароли, а md5 хэши, лучше дополнительно шифровать с кодовым словом
3. Админ, или юзер - не должно хранится в куках. Проверяйте это уже на бэкенде. Отдали куки (имя пользователя и хэш пароля) - поискали их в базе, нашли колонку с идентификатором роли пользователя, и уже от этого пляшем
4. Все-же лучше почитать, как делается авторизация пользователей, чтобы лучше понимать всю механику, и как это делать не стоит. Как у Вас сделано - точно не стоит

Comment: Сайт работает как показательный. Спасибо за ответ. Но тут не стоит смотреть на безопасность. Знаю, что ее тут нет. Я и не делал на ней акцент